# $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ of $|\sin{(n)}|^{\sin{(n)}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n =|\sin{(n)}|^{\sin{(n)}}$.

How can i find $\lim \sup a_n$ and $\lim \inf a_n$?

Comment: Hint. $\{\sin n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a dense subset of $[-1,1]$.

Comment: How can I prove it?

Comment: One possible way to prove is to use Dirichlet's approximation theorem.

Comment: I was able to prove that by proving '$(\cos(n), \sin(n))$ is dense in the unit circle'. Thank you.